# Using OpenCPU to access custom R function

Tags: javascript, r, api, opencpu

I have an R code which loads the RandomForest model, I am looking to create a function which

```
load(model)
randomforest_func = function(data) 
{
  data$pred = predict(model,data,type="prob")
  output = data.frame(data$customerid,data$pred[,2])
  return(output)
 }
```

I need to make this function enabled in webserver, where an external application feeds data and retrieves the output.

The problem is, the model needs to be preloaded and cannot load into R env for each request.

The function needs to support parallel connections.

I tried installing opencpu in R.

The above code should be running in R and available at
    http://localhost:1234/ocpu/

I now made changes to the `opencpu.js` to point to this URL and used the function in `jquery` to below. `ocpu.r_fun_call("randomforest_func",parameters)`

However this is seems to be not working..

`ocpu.r_fun_call` does not seem to be accessing the R script.

My question is how to correctly configure the opencpu to be able access the randomforest_func

Comment: What is your question? What does not work? What would you expect and what actually happens? Which errors do you see? Kindly provide us with details.

Comment: 'ocpu.r_fun_call("randomforest_func",parameters)' does not seem to access the **randomforest_func**

Comment: The goal is to get the jquery to be able access the function **randomforest_func**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/scoring-engine/) should help with deploying it as an app, making it easier for any external application to consume the services.

[This](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/publishing-data-with-opencpu/) should help with including the model.

Answer (score 0):

> The above code should be running in R and available at
>   http://localhost:1234/ocpu/

No. You need to create a package in which you put your custom functions. If the package is called `foo`, then the app will be available at

```
http://localhost:xxxx/ocpu/library/foo/www
```

(where `xxxx` is a random value for the port, given when you run `opencpu$browse()`). 
Also, you have to use `ocpu.call`, not `ocpu.r_fun_call`.